# Completely disable Http 404/500 templates when Debug=False

Tags: python, django, exception

I'm writing some methods in Django that return json. I'm handling exceptions myself and in certain scenarios, I want to return an Http 500 response with a Json body so the client can extract (amongst other things) an Exception uuid.

This worked fine with `Debug = True` but when set to `False`, the following code results in an *html* error page...

```
Ret = {"ExceptionId:": "<Exception_uuid>",
       "Message": "Some user-friendly error message"}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(Ret), content_type="application/json", status=INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I'm aware of the security implications which is why the Message returned here is in no way related to the exception but is generated by our own code when an exception is raised (or a generic one provided in some circumstances). The uuid is logged (ideally to database but to file if that's not possible) along with stack traces, the real exception information, etc. The user can refer to the exception by uuid when contacting us.

How can I force django *not* to try and interfere with a fuzzy html page that I don't want or need?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to return an Http 500 response with a Json body so the
>   client can extract (amongst other things) an Exception uuid.

TBH, I wouldn't bank on all web browsers treating non-200 responses as valid XHR responses, so it's probably safer to always return a 200 response when you plan to return a JSON response that you want the browser to parse.

One common way to do this is to return the same structure for all JSON responses, such that the browser can determine if the call succeeded or not. For example, you could return something like this...

```
{"result": "Hello, world!", "exception": null}
```

...if it worked, and something like this...

```
{"result": null, "exception": "You provided incorrect parameters"}
```

...if it fails. For bonus points, you could even translate the exception into a JavaScript exception, and throw it back to the calling function.

**Update**

To simplify processing, it's a lot easier if all your AJAX calls are routed through a single function. Something like...

```
function do_json_call(url)
{
    var json = null;
    // code to get JSON via XHR here
    var result = json['result'];
    var exc = json['exception'];
    if (exc !== null)
    {
        throw exc;
    }
    return result;
}

function func1()
{
    try
    {
        var result = do_json_call("http://localhost/json/func1");
        // Do something
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function func2()
{
    try
    {
        var result = do_json_call("http://localhost/json/func2");
        // Do something
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}

// etc..
```

Comment: This being an Api, all the calls are being made either via Ajax / by non-browser clients - so tbh I'm not particularly bothered if browsers will display the resulting body. I've already started down that route `({"Success": true, "Result": {...}}` or `({"Success": false, "Exception": {...}}` but it means that a lot of the javascript needs to be checking statuses and it's much cleaner to split it into jQuery's ajax `.success` and `.error` anonymous functions. I also need to be able to do 401/403 as appropriate which would mean _more_ status checking. I do take your point though

Comment: Thanks Aya, I've considered something similar, if a little more invovled (GET/POST, Postdata, callback functions, etc) and it's a definite possibility. +1 for the thoughts but I am going to hold on a while and see if I can stop Django stepping in with error pages

Answer (score 0):

In your `ROOT_URLCONF` i.e urls.py add an attribute named `handler500`.

urls.py

```
....
....
handler500 = 'myapp.views.get500handler'
```

myapp/views.py

```
def get500h(request):
    return HttpResponse("A server error ocurred")
```

Do not worry about what we are returning from `get500h()`, your user will still see the json response that you are returning.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain it to me? We specifically add a 500 handler which returns a request but it never gets used?